# swap never used, system freezes with high HD action when RAM is short

Tags: ubuntu, memory-usage, swap

My system freezes quite often when run out of memory, I have 2GB and using netbeans, chrome, firefox and a few other apps this is consumed completely. Seems to me since I upgraded to ubuntu natty.

ubuntu natty current

```
uname -a
2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

from /etc/fstab

```
UUID=7f3586b2-14c3-455c-a5bd-7adbc8174589 /srv            xfs     defaults        0       2
/dev/sda2       none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I tried setting

```
sysctl vm.swappiness=100
```

but no effect.  It' always like:

It looks always like that:

```
Every 2,0s: free -m                                         Wed Jul 13 20:20:26 2011

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1758       1697         61          0         55        633
-/+ buffers/cache:       1008        750
Swap:            0          0          0
```

What can I do to test if my swap works?

Comment: Step 1: Add some swap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what it looks like in your output, you have no swapspace at all active in this system.

Have you formatted your swap volume /dev/sda2 using the mkswap command?

If you run 'swapon -a' and then do a free -m, does it show any swap space?

The swappiness parameter will not do anything if you have no swap space of course.

Comment: Seems I havent read exactly the output of free... no swap at all! No idea why it wasn't setup in installation procedure - or maybe there was a prob on dist upgrade to natty.  Thx for your hint mdpc;  After `swapon -a` it, I see my 8393M swap space.  Where do I have to edit to make it activated on boot?